# Doctrine many-to-many association and mapping for a child table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two models User and Group. And I want to implement "many-to-many unidirectonal" mapping, using XML. In terms of database, I will have such tables

```
users
----- 
id
name

groups
------
id
name

user_groups
-----------
user_id
group_id
```

In code, I will have `addGroup` method in `User` class which will add multiple `Group` items to a `User` instance. I know, how to implement mapping for the `User` class, thanks to [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional). But unfortunatelly, it lacks mapping for the `Group` class, when this kind of "many-to-many unidirectional" association is used. So, what is the right way of implementing XML-mapping for the child `Group` class?

Comment: `unidirectional` means that there's one way link between entities. If you need two way links - that's `bidirectional`. And as you can note - tables structure for `unidirectional` lacks pivot table.

Comment: @u_mulder. As I said, I need one way link between entities.

Comment: Many-to-many unidirectional does not lack association table

Comment: Everything already described in the docs. Even with tables structure.

Comment: Please look at tables definition right below XML mapping for the User class. There you can see users_groups table. So, even though it is unidirectional, it has association or pivot table

Comment: @u_mulder. I do not agree, that everything is described. In this very block, mapping for the Group class is missing.

Comment: Okay my fault, Still, unidirectional means you can get `groups` from `user`, but cannot get `users` of `group`. That's why there's no need to describe anything in `Group` entity, because you won't need it.